# Iterating array-like objects using forEach, [].forEach.call(...) or Array.prototype.slice.call(...).forEach?

Tags: javascript

We can achieve iteration on array-like objects using both of the following methods:

```js
let arrayLike = document.getElementsByClassName('dummy');

[].forEach.call(arrayLike, (e) => {
  console.log(e);
});
```

```html
<div class = "dummy">Test1</div>
<div class = "dummy">Test2</div>
```

Or using `slice` to convert array-like objects to array first:

```js
let arrayLike = document.getElementsByClassName('dummy');

Array.prototype.slice.call(arrayLike).forEach((e) => {
  console.log(e);
});
```

```html
<div class = "dummy">Test1</div>
<div class = "dummy">Test2</div>
```

Which one is more preferrable and why in the case where I need not the converted array-like object? The first one feels a little 'hacky' but the second one feels more readable. Or are both just the same, meaning both will do just fine?

Comment: `[...arrayLike].forEach()` or `Array.from(arrayLike)`

Comment: Another option is [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration#for...of_statement)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could take [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) and convert the array like object to a real array. Then iterate with some of the array methods.

```js
let array = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('dummy'));

array.forEach((e) => {
    console.log(e);
});
```

```html
<div class = "dummy">Test1</div>
<div class = "dummy">Test2</div>
```

Comment: That's only supported in ES6 (2015), which I think is kinda new? I did think that it's so much cleaner, but am worried about its support.

Comment: Unless you plan to support <=IE11, looks like you're covered without a polyfill: [link](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-Array_static_methods_Array.from,_array-like_objects_a_href=_https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#Array_from_an_Array-like_object_(arguments)_title=_MDN_documentation_img_src=_../mdn.png_alt=_MDN_(Mozilla_Development_Network)_logo_width=_15_height=_13_/_/a_nbsp;)

Comment: you take arrow functions and `let.` it is supported in more or less any browser, without IE.

Comment: I'm not planning to support below IE11, if at all xD Thank you for the answer.

Comment: Oh just found out that the things I've used **are** from ES6. I was worried for nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use spread syntax

```js
[...document.getElementsByClassName('dummy')].forEach((e) => {
  e.classList.add('test')
});
```

```css
.test {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="dummy">Test1</div>
<div class="dummy">Test2</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Array.from`, `slice` or `...` (spreading):

```js
var divs = [...document.getElementsByClassName('dummy')]
divs.forEach(d => console.log(d));
var divs2 = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('dummy'));
divs2.forEach(d => console.log(d));
var divs3 = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('dummy'));
divs3.forEach(d => console.log(d));
```

```html
<div class="dummy">Test1</div>
<div class="dummy">Test2</div>
```